# TMX map not starting at x = 0. Android studio,

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, tiled, tmx

Im trying to move the map to x = 0. the player is spawning correctly at x = 0, and the camera as well but the map is not.

this is the map tmx (untitled.tmx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.10" tiledversion="1.10.2" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="128" height="32" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" infinite="0" nextlayerid="5" nextobjectid="1">
 <editorsettings>
  <export target="untitled.tmx" format="tmx"/>
 </editorsettings>
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="180" columns="18">
  <image source="tileset.png" width="576" height="320"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer id="1" name="sky" width="128" height="32" offsetx="2.30303" offsety="1.09091">
  <data encoding="csv">
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,
112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="2" name="ground" width="128" height="32" offsetx="2.30303" offsety="1.09091">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

This is the MapGame class:

```
public class MapGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private TiledMap tiledMap;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Player player;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        AssetManager assetManager = new AssetManager();
        assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
        assetManager.load("tilemap/untitled.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        assetManager.finishLoading();
        tiledMap = assetManager.get("tilemap/untitled.tmx", TiledMap.class);

        int screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        camera.position.set(0, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);

        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, 1);

        MapVar mapVar = new MapVar(tiledMap);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        player = new Player(0, screenHeight / 2);


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
                player.jump();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public void update() {
        updateCamera();
        player.checkGroundCollision();
    }


    private void updateCamera() {
        if(camera.position.x < MapVar.getMapWidthInPixels() - camera.viewportWidth / 2)
            camera.position.x +=2;

        camera.update();
    }


    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        player.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        update();

        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);

        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(player.getPlayerTextureRegion(), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        tiledMap.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the Player class:

```
public class Player {
    private final Vector2 position;
    private final Vector2 velocity;
    private boolean canMove;
    private final Animation<TextureRegion> playerAnimation;
    private float stateTime;
    private static final float JUMP_VELOCITY = 10 * 50; // Adjust the jump velocity as needed
    private static final float JUMP_DURATION = 0.5f; // Duration of the jump in seconds
    private static final float GRAVITY = -5500; // Adjust the gravity value as needed
    private boolean isJumping;
    private float jumpTime;
    public Player(int x, int y) {

        Texture playerSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet/run2.png"));

        int spriteColumns = 8;
        int spriteRows = 1;

        TextureRegion[][] playerFrames = TextureRegion.split(playerSheet, playerSheet.getWidth() / spriteColumns, playerSheet.getHeight() / spriteRows);

        Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < spriteRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < spriteColumns; j++) {
                frames.add(playerFrames[i][j]);
            }
        }

        playerAnimation = new Animation<>(0.1F, frames);
        playerAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);


        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        velocity = new Vector2();
        canMove = true;
        stateTime = 0;
        isJumping = false;
        jumpTime = 0;
    }

    public TextureRegion getPlayerTextureRegion() {
        return playerAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
    }

    public void jump() {
        if (!isJumping) {
            velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY;
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTime = 0;
        }
    }

    public void applyGravity(float deltaTime) {
        velocity.y += GRAVITY * deltaTime;
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {

        if (isJumping) {
            jumpTime += deltaTime;
            if (jumpTime >= JUMP_DURATION) {
                isJumping = false;
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
        }
        if (canMove && position.x <= MapVar.getMapWidthInPixels()) {
            float tileSize = MapVar.getTileWidthInPixels();
            float tilesPerSecondX = 5;

            velocity.x = tileSize * tilesPerSecondX;

            position.x += velocity.x * deltaTime;
            position.y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
        }
        stateTime += deltaTime;
    }

    public void checkGroundCollision() {
        int playerTileX = (int) (Math.ceil(position.x) / MapVar.getTileWidthInPixels());
        int playerTileY = (int)Math.ceil(position.y / MapVar.getTileHeightInPixels());

        int tileBelowValue = MapVar.getTileValue(playerTileX -2, playerTileY, "ground");

        if (tileBelowValue == 2) {
            position.y = (playerTileY + 1) * MapVar.getTileHeightInPixels();
            setJumping(false);
        }
        else if (tileBelowValue == 20) {
            position.y = (playerTileY + 2) * MapVar.getTileHeightInPixels();
            setJumping(false);
        }
        else if(tileBelowValue == 0){
            applyGravity(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        }
    }

    public void move(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        if(canMove){
            position.x += deltaX;
            position.y += deltaY;
        }
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
    }

    public void setVelocity(float x, float y) {
        velocity.set(x, y);
    }

    public boolean canMove() {
        return canMove;
    }

    public void setCanMove(boolean canMove) {
        this.canMove = canMove;
    }

    public boolean isJumping() {
        return isJumping;
    }

    public void setJumping(boolean jumping) {
        isJumping = jumping;
    }
}
```

[Image of the map in tiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBCZo.png)

[Image of the map in the game (The problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruNbU.png)

I dont know what to do anymore. please help me fix it, i would be so grateful!.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial camera position x is this

```
camera.position.set(0, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
```

and you update the tileMapRenderer with

```
tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
```

As far as the OrthogonalTileMapRenderer is concerned this sets the -center- of the camera (i.e. the center of the screen as you look at it) to x=0 of the tileMap coordinate system. So the position x=0 of the tileMap, the left of the map, renders at the center of the screen. The camera looks at x=0. What I mean is that the camera look at coordinates are centered, you are not specifying camera coordinates in terms of the lower left point of the viewport.